# UnknownApiNameOrVersion("name: %s version: %s" % (serviceName, version)) googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: webmasters version: v3

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api-webmasters

The following python script has been running as a cloud function on GCP, server us-central1 and has recently began to throw UnknownApiNameOrVersion error. The log shows error originating from webmasters build function mentioned below.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import json
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import secretmanager
import json

client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
secret = client.access_secret_version('...')

secret = json.loads(secret.payload.data.decode('UTF-8'))
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(secret, scopes=SCOPES)
webmaster = build(
    'webmasters',
    'v3',
    credentials=credentials
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but due to API changes you should make changes to your code:

- change **webmasters** to **searchconsole**
- change **v3** to **v1**

More info [here](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/12/search-console-api-updates#discovery-doc-migration)